# Using variants of 那

Tags: word-choice, usage

**When to use variations of 那?**

那 (nà,nǎ, nèi, núo) has multiple pronunciations. Can someone explain when to use the different sounds?

(images courtesy of www.zhongwen.com)

[image: nei@zhongwen.com][image: nei-radical@zhongwen.com]

Comment: we now write 哪里 and 哪个 instead of 那里 and 那个 for 'where' and 'which', respectively. This eliminates some ambiguities. As to the rest, you can say na4 in all circumstances; while many native speakers (perhaps not all) actually say [nə] in 那邊(there), 那個(that), etc.

Comment: @user58955 Define "we". I, for instance, never replace 那 by 哪 in *written* interrogatives. Admittedly, the differentiation between 那 and 哪 does eliminate a few ambiguities, but practically such ambiguities are rare.

Comment: @user1551 sorry, I meant in standard mandarin in mainland China.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**那 (nà)**: that, those

e.g 那是什么？What is that?/What are those?

**哪 (nǎ)**: where, which

e.g 你在哪里？Where are you?

**那 (nèi)**: that, those.

The same meaning as the first 那 (nà). But in "Internet Slang", people often write 内(nèi) instead of 那, because 那 is often pronounced as (nà)
e.g  那个人 That guy

**那 (nuó)**:【adj】 多,much,many

It is used in archaic Chinese.

More explanations about 那 can be found at:
http://xh.5156edu.com/html3/2193.html
http://www.zdic.net/z/26/js/90A3.htm

Comment: Refer to the answers in [this question](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1663/166) for more information regarding the `nèi` pronunciation.

The zdict.net link also provides the explanation of its derivation as a contraction of `nà yī` (那一).