# Word in Mandarin that is often used that sounds like "jigga"?

Tags: meaning, word

I saw this [Very frequently used word in Mandarin that sounds like "nica" or "nigah"](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/22145/4136) question, but I often hear another word in Chinese Mandarin that sounds like "jigga." It seems to be used very frequently and is almost certainly not a reference to Jay-Z.

Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word that sounds like "jigga" would be:

> [这个](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=2&wdqt=%E8%BF%99%E4%B8%AA%0D%0A)
>   zhè​ge

and it means:

> this / this one

---

It is sometimes also pronounced

> zhèi​ge

Which would account for any variations in pronunciation that you might hear.

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps 几个 （ji3 ge4) (which means "how many").

Answer (score 1):

"jigga" ：几个  （ji3 ge4) 
it means 'how many?' or  'several'. 
it depends on your tone, query  or indicative mood.

Answer (score 1):

Could also be  那个 (nèige) kinda sounds like a racial slur... It's like a pause or like the (well) in "well...i was just considering going shopping. Where in english you might say ummm or hmmm or well.